# jQuery adding extra variables to url

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-rest-framework

I think this is problem on frontend, and I am not familiar with frontend. So, this might not be the best method, suggestions are most welcome.

I need to get some data from a rest api developed via django-rest-framework and put it into the input field on a form.

So, this is the code,

```
function getcharmids(){
var get_url = "http://localhost:8000/get_charm_ids/" + name; # name I am declaring in the django template
console.log('clicked');
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    url: get_url,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    accept: "application/json",
    success: function(data){
        var charm_input = document.getElementById('id_charm_ids');
        console.log(charm_input.value);
        charm_input.value = data.charm_ids;
    },
});
};
```

So, it does call the URL, but with extra parameters.

It should call `http://localhost:8000/get_charm_ids/Kasam09`

But it calls with `/get_charm_ids/Shakti_02?callback=jQuery111009547658997639622_1518179689207&_=1518179689208`

So, due to extra parameters, my backend cannot process this request. What is the workaround to this problem?

What is the correct way to call apis via jquery?

Or is there any another good method?

EDIT -

Here is my api urls.py file,

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^get_data/(?P<vid>(.*?))$', views.get_data),
  url(r'^get_charm_ids/(?P<vid>(.*?))$', views.get_charm_ids),
]
```

Here is my views.py file,

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_data(request, vid):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        #here is my code
        return Response({'data':'a1,b2,c3,d4'})

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_charm_ids(request, vid):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        #here is my code
        return Response({'charm_ids':'1,2,3,4,5,6'})
```

Comment: give us an idea of how you build your html. it seems like name is being re assigned per loop or whatever that it doesn't get the expected name you're trying to get. also to it will help us identify where does that additional callback param came from.

Comment: I would also be interested to know why your backend "cannot process this request". Why doesn't it just ignore parameters it doesn't know about? What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using GET toward a URI, you could:

```
var get_url = "http://localhost:8000/get_charm_ids/?name=" + name;
```

where in Python Django you can than access is using `request.GET.get('name')`.

---

Another way is to request your *get_charm_ids* API

```
var get_url = "http://localhost:8000/get_charm_ids/";
```

and pass your **data** with your jQuery's `$.ajax` payload:

```
data: { "name": name },
```

Comment: Hey thanks mate, I have added more info in my question, can you please check it out and update in more detail?